# AngularJS custom filter with AND OR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to build a custom AND | OR filter for an ng-repeat.
My filter is an Array that looks like this

```
var filter = ['one', ['two', 'three']];
```

in my ng-repeat list there is an array with objects

```
var list = [{name: 'one', path:'two'}, {name: 'two', path: 'three'}, {name: 'three', path: 'four'}];
```

The filter i use to build should combine the first hierarchy of the filter by OR conditions and the second hierarchy by AND.
So if the filter is working the result should be list[0] and list[1].

Can anyone please help building up a filter that works like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show example in fiddle.

Comment: okay, i did a little try in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beiHirn/0f6pskLg/3/)